# Node Restify send back an integer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, bots, restify

[image]

This is what I get when I try to get my URL validated by Facebook for my bot. I know it's a data type issue. I am sending back a string instead of an int. Here's what my code looks like:

```
server.get("/webhook/",function(req,res,next){
    var token = req.query.hub.verify_token;
    if( token === process.env.VALIDATION_TOKEN ){
        var challenge = parseInt( req.query.hub.challenge );
        res.send( req.query.hub.challenge );
    }else{
        res.send("Error, wrong validation token");
    }
    return next();

});
```

Despite the `parseInt()`, `res.send()` sends back a string. How do I get it to send back an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out `res.send` only sends back an Object, Array, Buffer or String per the [restify docs](http://restify.com/#sendstatus-body) (though the same is true for express).

To send back an integer you have 2 (sorta 3) options:

1. Use a buffer like this:

   ```
   var buf = new Buffer(4);
   buf.writeUInt32BE(challenge, 0);
   res.send(buf);
   ```
2. Use `res.write(challenge)` or `res.end(challenge)`. For more information the docs are [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) and [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback).

Comment: Ok, turns out that req.query.hub.challenge is actually an integer. res.send() makes it a string

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I don't wanna get into the depths of it but res.write() and res.end() did the magic :)

Comment: @LittleChild yeah I was about to respond with that or the approach of using a buffer. I'll update my answer in case any one else stumbles upon this question

Comment: @LittleChild I've updated my answer to show how you can use can use `res.send`

Comment: I am using Node Restify :) Not Express :) but i'll still accept the answer

Comment: @LittleChild yeah I noticed that after writing my comment and updated my answer for that as well :)

Comment: What's the best way to listen for errors in Node Restify? How do I get it to print the stack trace if things go wrong?

Comment: you can always surround your routes with try catch's and console.log(e.stack);

Answer (score 0):

You can try `res.end(req.query.hub.challenge.toString());`

What I learnt that `res.end` expects to have a `String` type as parameter. So, converting the number into a string might work.